# How to start a ggplot with a negative x axis value when data do not contain negative value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some labels in the data that I want to annotate on the plot. I am trying to use `directlabels` package for annotation. Following is what I get:

```
library(directlabels)
ggplot(data =appr_CF_nlc %>% filter(SP_AB_Gp==7), 
       aes(x = frame_index, y = LV_frspacing.m, color = label, group=label)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_dl(aes(label = label), method = list(dl.trans(x = x+.2), "first.points"))
```

[image]

You can see that labels are not completely visible. How can I fix this? I have tried using `scale_x_continuous` with no luck:

```
ggplot(data =appr_CF_nlc %>% filter(SP_AB_Gp==7), 
       aes(x = frame_index, y = LV_frspacing.m, color = label, group=label)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_dl(aes(label = label), method = list(dl.trans(x = x + 0.), "first.points")) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0.5,0), limits=c(0, 3500))
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you use `+ xlim(...)` ?

Comment: Use `expand_scale` inside your `scale_x_continuous`